# SpringBoot define custome annotation include @Configuration @ImportResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

I'm try to define a custome annotation include @Configuration and @ImportResource

but @ImportResource doesn't work

Any suggestions?

```
@Documented
@Configuration
@ImportResource
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnableXXConfiguration {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ImportResource.class , attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ImportResource contains two attributes value and locations. The value attribute is ultimately alias for locations attribute so using either of the aliases works fine. Keeping your Custom annotation(EnableXXConfiguration) declaration (the one using value attribute) as it, use below code snippet.

```
@EnableXXConfiguration(value = { "context1.xml", "com/example/stackoverflow/context2.xml"})
public class DemoApp {

    @Autowired
    private BeanA beanA;

    @Autowired
    private BeanB beanB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApp.class);
        DemoApp demoAppObj = (DemoApp) context.getBean("demoApp");
        System.out.println("BeanA member: " + demoAppObj.getBeanA());
        System.out.println("BeanB member: " + demoAppObj.getBeanB());
    }

    public BeanA getBeanA() {
        return beanA;
    }

    public BeanB getBeanB() {
        return beanB;
    }
}
```

Assume we are using two xmlss placed at two different locations. context1.xml is placed in resource folder(src/main/resource) and context2.xml is placed at any other location (here at: src/main/java/com/example/stackoverflow)

context1.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="beanA" class="com.example.stackoverflow.BeanA" />

</beans>
```

context2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="beanB" class="com.example.stackoverflow.BeanB" />

</beans>
```

Comment: I did the same thing before, but it did not take effect. I customized a Spring xsd and wanted to import the configuration file with a custom annotation, but the "NameSpaceHanlder" was not loaded. The "AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.getMergedAnnotationAttributes" method did not return the value of annotation Until I replace "value with" localtions "